# Spring cache @Cacheable and @CachePut. If exception is thrown inside method of @cachePut, get data from Cache

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

I have a spring cache requirement:

I need to request to a server to get some data and store the results in spring cache. The same request can give me different results every time so I decided to use @cachePut so that every time I can go inside my function and cache gets updated.

```
@CachePut(value="mycache", key="#url")
public String getData(String url){
    try{
        // get the data from server
        // update the cache
        // return data
    } catch(){
        // return data from cache
    }   
}
```

Now there is a twist. If the server is down and I am not able to get the response; I want my data from the cache (stored in previous requests).

If i use `@Cacheable`, I can't get the updated data. What is the clean way to do this? Something like catching an exception and return the data from cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get the cache implementation like this and handle the cache.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheConfig;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachePut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheNames="mycache") // refer to cache/ehcache-xxxx.xml 
public class CacheService {
    @Autowired private CacheManager manager;
    @CachePut(key="#url")
    public String getData(String url) {
        try {
            //do something.
            return null;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            Cache cache = manager.getCache("mycache");
            return (String) cache.get(url).get();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cache.get(url).get() is throwing null pointer exception. But when i debug i can see my data in cache vaiable. cache-->store-->can see my data

Comment: sure, you must put a value to the cache before get from it.

Comment: i mean i already placed the cache value. but retrieving that value is giving me NPE

Comment: minor correction and it worked for me:  ConcurrentMap<String, String> map = (ConcurrentMap<String, String>)cache.getNativeCache();
   response = map.get(key);